# storing contents of php://input in a variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, http-headers

I'm trying to edit and tweak someone else's REST server in PHP. It's based on the [REST Server](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver) written by Phil Sturgeon. Pretty much got my head around all of it, but my requests aren't working as expected.

In the server constructor is the code

```
switch ($this->request->method)
{
    case 'post':
    $this->_post_args = $_POST;
    $this->request->format and $this->request->body = 
                                    file_get_contents('php://input');
    break;
}
```

I know that `php://input` can only be read once, so doing `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'))` before setting the variables shows that my XML data is being read correctly from the input stream but obviously the variables aren't set right.

But doing `var_dump($this->request->body)` only outputs `NULL`! Is there a special technique to storing the contents of `php://input` in a variable?

EDIT:

I'm using [API Kitchen](http://apikitchen.com/) to send the POST request and the headers that it sends are

```
Status: 200
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.11
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2012 11:00:43 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Content-Length: 936
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I can't see from this what the encoding is.

EDIT 3:

The encoding is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which could be where the problem lies!! How do I specifically say what this should be?

EDIT 2:

`$this->request->method` contains `'post'`

Comment: What type of object is `$this->request`?

Comment: `$this->request` is declared as `protected $request = NULL; // Stores accept, language, body, headers, etc`

Comment: I can't find a separate implementation or anything, the first time it's set is in the same constructor and it's set with `$this->request->method = $this->_detect_method();`. Sorry I don't seem to be being very helpful here!

Comment: it's someone else's code

Comment: debug by inserting the print statements. and break down the compound statement.

Comment: dumping the vars separately prints `NULL` for both and when `var_dump($this->request->format and $this->request->body);` prints `bool(false)`

Comment: `php://input` won't work with multipart/formdata but you mentioned this is not the case. You then say that `$this->request->format` prints `NULL`, you're effectively doing something like `null and $a = 1;` which means `$a = ...;` part does not execute at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all the help, it turns out that in order to work, the content type of the request must be application/xml, not application/x-www-form-urlencoded as it was.

Answer (score 1):

if `$this->request->format` evaluates to `false` or `NULL` or `0`, the later part of `and` operator does not execute.

```
  $this->request->format and $this->request->body = file_get_contents('php://input');
                             ^
                             |
                             +--- this part wont execute
```

You should have written it like

```
if($this->request->format){
    $this->request->body = file_get_contents('php://input');
}
```

This helps in debugging.